# Instagram Location Endpoint only showing user's data - not public

Tags: api, location, coordinates, instagram

I'm playing with Instagram's API and want to get all *public* photos near the coordinates provided.

I call the URL: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=40.730610&lng=-73.935242&access_token=MY_TOKEN&distance=5000

but it is only showing *my* photos taken near those coordinates, not all the *public* ones. Am I missing some sort of parameter, or am I misunderstanding the purpose of this API call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it does display all content but only outside of sandbox mode. Only displays media from the users in the sandbox whilst in sandbox mode even if you request public media.